# Properly escaping backslash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a problem with escaping backslash in query. I have a model Report that looks like this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

and model Person that looks like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :middle_name
end
```

And I have query that looks like this:

```
Report.includes(:person).where("concat_ws(' ', lower(people.first_name), lower(people.middle_name), lower(people.last_name)) ~* :keyword", {keyword: "User name"}).references(:people)
```

The problem with that query is that is not working when user type in search backslash:

```
Report.includes(:person).where("concat_ws(' ', lower(people.first_name), lower(people.middle_name), lower(people.last_name)) ~* :keyword", {keyword: "User name\"}).references(:people)
```

then it returns:

```
PG::InvalidRegularExpression: ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence
```

Comment: Using actual input from a user? Or just because you placed the backslash there yourself?

Comment: To describe a problem i put myself backslash here but when user types it returns:
PG::InvalidRegularExpression: ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence

Comment: How are you loading the `keyword` variable from the user? Through rails params, request vars, something else? Just curious as to how it is sanitized

Comment: Yeah I load string that user pass in keyword field from params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LIKE` in your query, instead of a `~*`, this way user input won't be interpreted as a regular expression.

UPDATE: Enclose your user input in `%`, like this:

```
Report.includes(:person).where("concat_ws(' ', people.first_name, people.middle_name, people.last_name) ILIKE :keyword", { keyword: "%#{params[:input]}%" }).references(:people)
```

ILIKE performs case-insensitive search, so you don't need that `lower` anymore.

You may also need to escape any `_` or `%` in user input so it won't get interpreted by Postgres as a special symbol (`_` stands for any character and `%` stands for any quantity of characters).

Look into [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html) for details and examples. Have a nice day!

Comment: Now when I type part of first, middle or last name it properly search me person. After changing this for LIKE it will not work in this way...